# What has 7 Brachos before the act

Tags: halacha, blessing

**What has 7 Brachos before the act? Examples I can think of are; Matza, Nesuin... Is there anything else that we make 7 Brachos on before we do it?**

*Ps: This question will help me resolve a Mahril brought in the K' Nesanel on the Rosh in Pesachim 49a based on a Yerushalmi*

Comment: The bracha of *she lo asani isha* in the morning? ;->

Comment: Ha. Not bad lol

Comment: Which brachot count? We don't make 7 brachot on matza, and there were 9 blessings said at the last chuppa I attended

Comment: See the Karbon Nesanel there

Comment: I doubt I'll get a chance to anytime soon, but without any reasonable definition in this question, I think it should be closed. No one can tell how to answer it.

Comment: If you see the k"nesanel he quotes a mahril and the question the oilam asks is what's the mahril saying, what's the wedding that's taking place

Comment: I shouldn't need to go see a k"nesanel to understand a question. [Edit] into the question explicitly what the relavent definition of "saying a bracha on something" is. That way people can know what kinds of things you seek as answers.

Comment: @Moshe Does the question mean an act that happens to have 7 blessings that are said before it (not 7 blessings on the actual act)?

Comment: @Dani Remember everything I do each day after saying at least 7 blessings (which is the vast majority of things) have at least 7 blessings said before it is done.

Comment: *that are related to the act.

Comment: @Dani Is all of shacharis related to any food I eat that day since I can't eat at least until I've davened?